# PYGAME, check for second press

Tags: python, pygame

So I want to change the variable from `False` to `True` on the first key press, and then on the second press (of the same key for e.g. "g") I want the variable to change back to "False"

Here is an example of not working code:

```py
...

if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    if event.key == pygame.K_g:
        show_location=True
if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    if event.key == pygame.K_g:
        show_location=False
...
```

Can someone explain to me how to do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than hard-coding `True` or `False` in your assignment, just negate the current value:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    if event.key == pygame.K_g:
        show_location = not show_location
```